# How to pass hidden field value to query string in asp.net view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, hidden-field

I am using asp.net mvc with razor view.I have a scenario where I have to pass the hidden field value to query string and access the value. I've declared the hidden field but the problem is that I cannot access the hidden field.

The declaration of hidden field goes here

```
@model CloudCashWizard.Models.CashSafeLockViewModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = CloudCashWizard.Resources.Resources.AMSEC;
   <input type="hidden" value="@Model.CashSafeLockView.DoorNumber" id="hFieldDoorNumber" 
   name="hFieldDoorNumber" />
}
```

Want to access the hidden field here at DoorNo

```
 <a  id="LCPrint" href = "@Url.Content("~/Aspx/LockConfiguration.aspx? 
  CashSafeId="+Model.CashSafeLockView.CashSafeId+"&DoorNo="+Hiddenfield)" class="btn btn-primary
 btn-Addbutton"><i class="icon icon-white icon-print"></i>Print</a>
```

How can I do that?Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

M.b that's easier to create form with GET method and it will assemble proper URL by itself, based on fields inside that form.
Example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
  @Html.Hidden("CashSafeId", Model.CashSafeLockView.CashSafeId);
  @Html.Hidden("DoorNo", Model.CashSafeLockView.DoorNumber);

  <button type="button"><i class="icon icon-white icon-print"></i>Print</button> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
      $(e).attr("href", $(e).attr("href") + '&ParamName='+$('#hFieldDoorNumber').val();
   });
});
```

Comment: In the above case how can I append the hiddenvalue to query string.

Comment: The desired value is sent via your model to the view, right? If yes the value will automatically added to the request if you are using "GET" and will pass automatically to server as post data if you are using "POST"

Comment: I think you haven't understood my question.I got the desired value from the model to view.I want to place this value in a hidden field,then pass the hidden field as a query string to an aspx page on a button click.

Comment: Does your button make a 'submit'? and also you can change the hidden value by jquery if it is calculated on client side.

Comment: Actually im not using button,im using an anchor tag as given above.On clicking the anchor tag user will be taken to the aspx page.I want to append the hiddenfield value as query string so that it can be parsed from the aspx page